# iOS Universal Link with a second level subdomain doesn't deep-link to native app, but deep-links fine on a first-level subdomain (same host)

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have capabilities in my app that contain multiple applinks: entries like so:

```
applinks:firstlevel.domain.com
applinks:second.level.domain.com
```

Universal links on the first level subdomain work fine and open the app. 
Universal links on the second level subdomain do NOT open the app (go to safari).  My suspicion right now is because of the composite (2-piece) subdomain.

The apple-app-site-association files are **completely identical on both**, and are hosted and downloadable from both. 
Both URLs are hittable from our internal network and are on the same domain and TLD.   SSL is configured correctly.  There are no redirects taking place (verified through chrome dev tools)

Each respective **apple-app-site-association** file is hosted under appropriate subdomain (not on the root of domain.com).  But the **same top level domain is used for both subdomains in URL 1 and 2**.

Can the second-level subdomain be the problem, or is it more likely that other network configuration differences are the problem?  I couldn't find information online that states whether multiple subdomains are supported for universal links or not.

UPDATE: Tried removing the applinks:firstlevel.domain.com entry, to make sure the two subdomains aren't conflicting for the same bundle ID (and the site association).  This did not make a difference.  The second level subdomain still doesn't deep-link.

Any suggestions on how to diagnose why the second URL can not be opened as a deeplink in the app?

It's also not appropriate to use wildcards or upload the apple-app-site-association file to the root of the domain, because that's production, and should not have any lower environment settings on it.

Here's our apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
    'webcredentials': {
        'apps': ['ourteamid.ca.ourdomain.ourname']
    },
    'applinks': {
        'apps': [],
        'details': [{
            'appID': 'ourteamid.com.ourdomain.ourname1.ourname2',
            'paths': ['r/samplepath/*', 'en/r/samplepath/*', 
'fr/r/samplepath/*']
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem. Did you find answer?

Comment: No.  We are blocked.

Comment: Mm... 
Found out that i don't have issue :)
If hold dynamic link pressed, iOS will ask which app to use for this link. 
So seems like i chose Safari first time and next time it always open with it.
Try to use new device for test.

Comment: Found the problem.  Single quotes in the association file instead of double quotes....  SIngle quotes aren't valid in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution.  It was the single quotes in the apple-app-site-association file (single quotes are not valid JSON).  Apple's examples all use double quotes.

At some point, someone converted it to single quotes, and uploaded the file, and we did not catch it. The deeplinks work fine with double quotes in the file, and it had nothing to do with a second level domain.

Updated association file:

```
    {
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": ["ourteamid.ca.ourdomain.ourname"]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "ourteamid.com.ourdomain.ourname1.ourname2",
            "paths": ["r/samplepath/*", "en/r/samplepath/*", "fr/r/samplepath/*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using double quotes. Any idea what is causing this issue?